# Round numbers in array to 2 decimals

Tags: php

In a array of numbers that have 4 decimals, how can I round them with only 2 decimals? I'm also using a str_replace to replace commas with dots.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {

  $vf .= str_replace(",", ".", round($value['vf'])); // gives 1.111, 2.222 etc
  $vf .= str_replace(",", ".", round($value['vf'],2)); // does nothing
}
```

How can I round the values to a number with 2 digits, like 1.11?

Comment: Seriously `php round values` shows you nothing?

Comment: `round` it should work

Comment: [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is your friend, specially when you need custom grouped thousands

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$n = 12.34567890;
echo number_format($n, 2, '.');
// 12.35
```

You can even use it to add a thousands separator:

```
$n = 12345.67890;
echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ',');
// 12,345.68
```

Or you can use [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

```
$n = 12.34567890;
echo round($n, 2);
// 12.35
```